# How to create a global variable to hold a instance that has generic abstract class ? Or is it even a right thing?

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, mvvm

I have a WPF application where I have a dedicated presenter for each view and some parts of the application are tasks that uses AbstractTaskPresenter like below.

**TaskPresenter**

```
public sealed class AbcTaskPresenter : AbstractTaskPresenter<AbcTaskViewModel>
{
   private AbcTaskPresenter() : base(new AbcTaskViewModel())
    {
    }
    //ViewModel is used here
    ...
 }
```

**AbstractTaskPresenter**

```
public abstract class AbstractTaskPresenter<TViewModel> : PresenterBase<TViewModel> where TViewModel : AbstractTaskViewModel
{
 public event EventHandler SaveTaskRequested;

//ViewModel is also used here
...
}
```

**PresenterBase**

```
public abstract class PresenterBase<TViewModel> : IDisposable where TViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
  protected TViewModel ViewModel { get; }

//ViewModel is also used here
...
}
```

And my problem is here...
In a main application presenter, I declare this global variable that says

```
protected AbstractTaskPresenter commonPresenter{ get; set; }
```

So in the Main application presenter, I can register for the AbstractTaskPersenter events.

But the problem is here. Now since I have the Generics in the abstract classes, the variable declaration always has this error. Not sure how to go about this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a non-generic `PresenterBaseBase`

Comment: Well `AbstractTaskPresenter` is not "is-a" `AbstractTaskPresenter<T>`. In fact, `AbstractTaskPresenter` does not seem to exist, even. Now, my first question would be: If you have the need for a "global" AbstractTaskPresenter `commonPresenter` - then why is the class generic?

Comment: @Fildor Like I mentioned in the description, the so called "Task" Persenters will use this AbstractTaskPersenter and so in order to perform some exit functions in global scope, I need this.

Comment: @Charlieface I need the Generic there bcoz I have ViewModel instance used in the presenter base.

Comment: `PresenterBase<TViewModel>` should inherit from `PresenterBaseBase`

Comment: I think this lacks some detail.

Comment: @Fildor I have some updates on the problem description. FYI

Comment: I have the strong suspicion, the solution would simply be "Composition over Inheritance". If your `AbstractTaskPresenter` wasn't itself Generic but could _take_ some generic "behavior"-Class ... maybe? Or asked differently: What would be an example, where `AbstractTaskPresenter` _must_ know the exact type of the ViewModel?

Comment: @Fildor The methods in AbstractTaskPresenter can use only properties and methods of AbstractTaskViewModel and ViewModelBase and no access for AbcTaskViewModel properties and methods.

Comment: Exactly. So, the fact that you need to keep that type in your inheritance tree is keeping you from achieving your goal. One way to address that is to move inheritance away in favor of composition.